# How to handle multiple events associated with select tag using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building a shopping website whereby I give the users the opportunity to filter the food items according to category and price (Low to high and vice-versa). I have implemented this using a dropdown list.

I am now having an issue displaying the products. I have to use AJAX to filter the results. On page load I have set the default category to 'All' where all the food items have to be displayed and as I change the category the food items get filtered accordingly.

The issue is that I use `$("#Category option:selected").val()`. I get the value as the page gets loaded and if I use on change, there will be an action only on change but nothing happens on default value. How shall I handle this?

```html
<div class="collapse" id="filterdiv">
  <form class="d-inline">
    <select id="Category">
      <option value='' selected>All</option>
      <?php 
        $fCategory="SELECT DISTINCT Food_Type from food";
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $res=$conn->query($fCategory);

        if($res->rowCount()>0)
        {
          while($row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
          {
            echo "<option value=".$conn->quote($row['Food_Type']).">".$row['Food_Type']."</option>";
          }
        }
      ?>
    </select>

    <select id="price">
      <option value="">Price</option>
      <option value="lowtohigh">Low to High</option>
      <option value="hightolow">High to Low</option>
      <</select>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row" id="result">
  <!-- I will display the result from the query here using ajax -->
</div>
```

Comment: You've missed the most important part of the code from the question - the JS. However it sounds like you just need to call `trigger('change')` on the `select` when the page loads. Also note that `$("#Category option:selected").val()` can be shortened to just `("#Category").val()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually I wrote the js but did not attach it as it did not work. Can you write it for me please?

Comment: Sorry, no. This site is for help debugging existing code, not for writing code on your behalf.

Comment: @Roy McCrossan ok but won't the on change event only happen when the user selects a category? I want that even if he does not select, that is 'all', the products shall be displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger a change event on the `select` when the page loads it will call the `onchange` event handler you have set up (you do have one right?)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#Category').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: it is not working.. Giving me blank output when im doing an alert

Comment: In your Category `select` you have `value=''` as your first option. I can't see the code that is generating the alert, but this is probably what is being sent. Try changing the first option to `<option value='All' selected>All</option>`